# JavaFX KeyEvent and accented characters

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I'm using a WebView with a contenteditable body as a rich text editor in JavaFX. It's working fine, but I need to listen for key presses. It works for the enter key and ASCII characters, but accented characters (like the icelandic á and é) don't fire any event. I tried KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED and KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, and neither of them fire for accented characters.

InputMethodEvent does fire for accented characters, but if I setup a listener for that, it seems to automatically consume the event and it doesn't get to the editor.

Anybody know of a way to listen for event when accented characters are typed that doesn't consume them or of a way to unconsume the character in InputMethodEvent?

Comment: Which OS, and JavaFX version do you use?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an KeyEvent EventHandler to any Node (in this case your WebView) with the [Node.addEventHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#addEventHandler-javafx.event.EventType-javafx.event.EventHandler-) method, and if you handle the EventType *KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED* you can get the typed **unicode** characters with the [KeyEvent.getCharacter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#getCharacter--) method. See this example:

```
WebView myWebView = new WebView();
myWebView.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED,
                    new EventHandler<KeyEvent>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void handle(KeyEvent event)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Unicode character typed: "+event.getCharacter());

                            switch (event.getCharacter())
                            {
                            case "á":
                                System.out.println("Typed accented a");
                                break;
                            case "é":
                                System.out.println("Typed accented e");
                                break;
                            case "í":
                                System.out.println("Typed accented i");
                                break;
                            case "ó":
                                System.out.println("Typed accented o");
                                break;
                            case "ú":
                                System.out.println("Typed accented u");
                                break;
                            default:
                                System.out.println("Typed other key " + event.getCode());
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                    });
```

You might want to take a look at the [Collator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) class if you want to compare different strings ignoring locale, uppercase, lowercase, etc. It might be useful if you want to consider "á" and "a" equal.

Good luck!