# JavaFX - get KeyEvent for non-ASCII characters

Tags: java, javafx, keyboard-events, scalafx

In  a JavaFX (actually ScalaFX) application, I would like to allow the user to invoke commands by a sequence of keyboard keys. These commands should work regardless of the current keyboard layout (language). for example, the user may be typing in Thai (ภาษา) and then want to save by pressing 'Escape' and than 'S' (or ':' and then 'w', vim style).

I have found that KeyEvents give undefined key code for non-English (non-ASCII?) characters.

This code:

```
onKeyPressed = (k: KeyEvent) => {
  println("text: " + k.text + "  " + "code name: " + k.code.name)
}
```

gives:

```
text: a  code name: A  
text:   code name: Alt          << Alt + Shift switches from English to Hebrew
text:   code name: Shift  
text: ש  code name: Undefined
```

when pressing A, changing language to Hebrew and pressing it again.

**How can I overcome this problem?** how can I know which key was pressed regardless of language?

similar unanswered question: [JavaFX KeyEvent and accented characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984743/javafx-keyevent-and-accented-characters)

Answer (score 0):

[`getCharacter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#getCharacter%28%29) will get you the unicode character behind the `KeyEvent`:

> The unicode character associated with the key typed event. For
>   example, char will have the value "A" for a key typed event generated
>   by pressing SHIFT + 'a'. For key pressed and key released events, char
>   is always CHAR_UNDEFINED.

Comment: This is better than what I got, but still not allowing me to know **which key was pressed regardless of language**. Since I don't know what language the user is using, I will have to examine many many unicode characters in order to identify the same key stroke.